# backbone.js pass param from router to views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

Below is my router function where i have an id as the parameter.My question is how to pass the id into the camp views..Thanks..i tried the following..When i do a alert in views it says undefined

Router.js

```
editcampaign :function(id){
        $('#content').empty();
        require([ 'views/camp' ], function(editcampaign) {
            $('#content').html(new editcampaign({campaignID:id}).render().$el);
        });
    },
```

Views.js

```
  SM.Views.editCampaign = Backbone.View.extend({myid:id ,

        template : _.template(Editcampaigntnpl),
        campaignID : 0,
        initialize : function() {
            _self1=this;
            alert(myid); //this says undefined
            this.campaign = new Campaign();
            this.newscenario = new Newscenarioview();
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your initialize function as first line:

```
initialize : function(options) {
        this.campaignID = options.campaignID; // <===
        this.myid = options.campaignID;

        _self1=this;
        alert(myid); //this says undefined
        this.campaign = new Campaign();
        this.newscenario = new Newscenarioview();
},
```